# boto3 s3 put_object times out

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

I've got a python script that Works On My Machine (OSX, python 2.7.13, boto3 1.4.4) but won't work for my colleague (Windows7, otherwise same).

The authentication seems to work, and we can both s3's list_objects_v2 and get_object. However when he tries to upload with put_object, it times out. Here is [a full log](https://gist.github.com/rcteske/e1e7b3499f080b26f3697f239e4269a4); the upload starts at line 45.

I've tried using his credentials and it works. He's tried uploading a tiny file and it'll work when it's in the bytes range, but even kb is too big for it. We've even tried it on another windows machine on another internet connection with no luck.

My upload code is pretty simple:

```
with open("tmp_build.zip", "r") as zip_to_upload:
  upload_response = s3.put_object(Bucket=target_bucket, Body=zip_to_upload, Key=build_type+".zip")
```

The Key resolves to test.zip in our runs, and the file is about 15mb.

Why is it failing on windows? What more debug info can I give you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using inspiration from this https://github.com/boto/boto3/issues/870 issue, I added `.read()` to my Body parameter, and lo it works.

Comment: Apparently this is an API issues.

Answer (score -1):

Might be network issues. are you on the same network?

are you able to upload it using the AWS-CLI
try the following

```
aws s3 cp my-file.txt s3://my-s3-bucket/data/ --debug
```

also I would consider adding X retries to the upload might give you more information on the error at hand. most of the times these are sporadic network related issues